# Can Jinns be controlled by humans?

Tags: jinn

In the story quoted below, 'I' means it's me.

> I remember an old person from my mother's hometown. He was some Peer or Murid, I guess. He always wore Black Kurta with a white Izaar and a green turban. He was close to my maternal relatives. Whenever he visited us, if I happened to be around, he used to call me by his side and pass his hand through beard and miraculously get me some peanuts or peppermints with a friendly smile. When I asked "how did you do that?", he never said anything. When I asked my mother about it, she told me that he possessed (Has control over) some Jinns and by running hand through his beard, he makes some gestures to the Jinns and they obey it. I was less than 8 then.
>
> Slowly, after years went by, I started thinking that he had tricked me by hiding substances in his long beard and tricks all the people in this way and has no control over Jinns. I strongly believed that he was a trickster until I was around 15 when I happened to be around him once again. He had grown weak. As I was not a little boy, meeting him was just a matter of Salaam and no peanuts or peppermints. This time he was thirsty, and asked my cousin for a glass of water. She (my cousin) said to him: "Why don't you get a lemon? I'll prepare some sweet lemon water for you.". Nodding his head in agreement he again ran both his hands through his beard and believe me, there was a lemon in his hand. I was watching this and am sure that before running his hand through his beard, he had nothing in his hand. Also, if he was a trickster how could he get nothing other than lemon? I mean, To test him, people may ask him to get anything at anytime just like my cousin did. It is impossible to carry everything in a beard.
>
> Though I can remember only these two instances, many people in the town (Tiptur in Karnataka state of India) have similar stories to say. Unfortunately, Khaleel Hazrath(The old man) met with a train accident a few years back and is no more.

In the long story, one thing might be clear to you: I cannot disbelieve what I have seen with my eyes. But, In no way I am forcing anyone to believe. So maybe Allah has proved to me that this kind of magical stuff can happen. But **is this stuff usual?**, **In the history (other than that of Prophets) and scriptures of Islam, has such a thing ever been witnessed?** And most importantly, **Can Jinn be possessed (If possessed is not the right word, Controlled) by a human?**

We have heard of stories like Messengers of Allah (especially Sulaiman [pbuh]) could order Jinns. But Khaleel Hazrath was a common but a pious man, maybe he was a Hafiz (not necessarily) because I have seen him teaching Qur'an to children.

Comment: The word "control" isn't appropriate as it conveys a false sense of coercing kind of power over something. "Collaborate," perhaps is the right word?

Comment: I recommend reading the book "The Elixir of Love" about Rajab Ali, who had even more impressive skills. It has nothing to do with jinns, nor anything one should be feared of.

Answer (score 10):

I do not want to judge your story was real or not but yes it can be and already some people do it.

Some control them for evil reasons like magic and some use it for good reasons.

And the proof is this verse of Quran:

[[27:17]](http://tanzil.net/#27:17)

> وَحُشِرَ لِسُلَيْمَانَ جُنُودُهُ مِنَ الْجِنِّ وَالْإِنسِ وَالطَّيْرِ
>   فَهُمْ يُوزَعُونَ
>
> And gathered for Solomon were his soldiers of the jinn and men and
>   birds, and they were [marching] in rows.

The large castle of prophet Solomon was made by working of many Jinns for him.

Please note controlling Jinns is Haram in Islam unless for few Awlia (close friends of God) who are allowed to use Jinns as servants to do orders of God.

Also in Shia Hadith Books there are many Hadith saying prophet and Ahl Bayt have servants from Jinn and used them when needed for example delivering a letter to someone in a far city quickly in one moment.

More info:

[Power of Satan and Jinn](http://www.al-islam.org/faith_reason/20.htm)

Comment: I request you plz cite one authentic Hadith which says "there are many Hadith saying prophet and Ahl Bayt have servants from Jinn" or the like

Comment: The phrasing "and gathered for solomon" could also suggest that someone else, maybe Allah himself gathered the jinn, men and birds for solomon. is that wrong interpretation?

Answer (score 2):

They cannot.

That power was given to Prophet Suliman and he alone as Allah says:

[image]

> He said, "My Lord, forgive me and grant me a kingdom such as will not belong to anyone after me. Indeed, You are the Bestower." [35:35]

Controlling the Jinn was one of those grants. This is also mentioned in this Sahih [hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/181440):

> حَدَّثَنَا إِسْحَاقُ بْنُ إِبْرَاهِيمَ، حَدَّثَنَا رَوْحٌ، وَمُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ، عَنْ شُعْبَةَ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ زِيَادٍ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّ عِفْرِيتًا مِنَ الْجِنِّ تَفَلَّتَ عَلَىَّ الْبَارِحَةَ ـ أَوْ كَلِمَةً نَحْوَهَا ـ لِيَقْطَعَ عَلَىَّ الصَّلاَةَ، فَأَمْكَنَنِي اللَّهُ مِنْهُ وَأَرَدْتُ أَنْ أَرْبِطَهُ إِلَى سَارِيَةٍ مِنْ سَوَارِي الْمَسْجِدِ حَتَّى تُصْبِحُوا وَتَنْظُرُوا إِلَيْهِ كُلُّكُمْ، فَذَكَرْتُ قَوْلَ أَخِي سُلَيْمَانَ رَبِّ هَبْ لِي مُلْكًا لاَ يَنْبَغِي لأَحَدٍ مِنْ بَعْدِي ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ رَوْحٌ فَرَدَّهُ خَاسِئًا‏.‏
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Last night a demon from the Jinns came to me (or the Prophet (ﷺ) said, a similar sentence) to disturb my prayer, but Allah gave me the power to overcome him. I intended to tie him to one of the pillars of the mosque till the morning so that all of you could see him, but then I remembered the Statement of my brother Solomon:--'My Lord! Forgive me and bestow on me a kingdom such as shall not belong to any other after me.' (38.35) The narrator added: Then he (the Prophet) dismissed him, rejected. 'Nor am I one of the pretenders (a person who pretends things which do not exist).' (38.86)

Comment: Kingdom is not the same as "control," and as beings with freedom of choice a Jinn can _voluntarily grant control_, just as a human can - even if just to demonstrate the possibility of "control." In that, it wouldn't be coercing power over somebody, but rather a cooperative willful obedience. Even Suleman (puh) didn't have the coercing kind of powers over even a Hoopoe, who made a choice to be late from the assembly, with a valid excuse.

Comment: +1. The references quoted definitely prove that Jinns ***shouldn't*** be controlled. But it doesn't prove whether it can altogether be ***done or not***.