# Are soothsayers and sorcerers allowed to become Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram, sihr, conversion

I realize that [studying sorcery or consulting a soothsayer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/what-is-the-magic-and-what-is-the-ruling-on-learning-it-in-islam/1285#1285) is unlawful, but I am confused as to whether or not someone who knew these practices would be able to become a Muslim. I am under the impression that anyone who says shahada and truly means it can become Muslim, but does certain knowledge forbid one entry into Allah's path?

I am looking for Qur'anic verses or hadiths that can help answer the question.

Comment: basically everyone can become Muslim - for example every juman being is accompanied by a Shaytaan, yet the Shaytaan accompanying our Prophet (SAWS+PBUH) became Muslim (with the help of Allah).

Comment: Another example: As it contained in Quran the magicians which where brought by Pharao to fight with Musa (A.S) became Muslim which lead to being crucified by Pharao...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quran is very clear on this subject. The only sin that will no be forgiven on the day of Judgment will be [Shirk](http://quran.com/4/48) (Knowingly associating partners with Allah). All other sins are pardonable.

This world is made for a test and if a person, no matter what his sins, repents and comes on the right path, he should be hopeful, that Allah will Forgive his sins.